# When calculating FPS in Unity, why does it count like this?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * .1f;
```

Here's an explanation of this formula :
"Since the framerate can vary constantly, it will change many times during a given second. I've used the following recommended approach to get the current framerate."

but, I didn't understand.
I would appreciate it if you could explain to me in more detail.

They all said they referenced the following link, but that link is broken.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: _"framerate... will change many times during a given second..."_ - I never understood the need for an _instantaneous_ framerate especially when the metric being measured is frames-per-**second**.  How can one come up with a meaningful answer when the sampling period is not yet complete.  Surely any result calculated in the first say 0.243324 seconds will be complete with errors as opposed to the 0.9873464 mark?

Comment: I checked the link you gave me. I like the calculation method in the link. easier to understand. I will refer to the link you sent me to calculate the FPS.
But still I don't understand this formula(deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * .1f;). I don't know why this formula calculates the modified deltaTime.

Comment: Looks more like some kind of smoothing to me .. of course you could as well simply use `1 / Time.deltaTime` but there might be a lot of peaks then